# Replace string in UNITEXT column sybase database

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase

We are using Sybase database and have the below table.

```
CREATE TABLE table_1
(id            VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
,data_values   UNITEXT         NULL
,last_modified DATETIME        NULL)
```

I have requirement to replace the word stored the data_values column which is of UNITEXT type.

I found [link](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1550/html/sqlug/sqlug217.html) but this is not helping how we can replace the words.

Query that I tried is below.

```
declare @val varbinary(16)
select  @val = textptr(data_values) from table_1
writetext table_1.data @val "Some text"
```

I have to dynamically generate the text to be set in data_values field. Text itself will be fetched from same column itself and have to processed(few words changes) before setting to the field.

Comment: I'd recommend you review [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then update your question; in particular, what query have you tried, what was the result (error? wrong/incorrect result?) and what is the desired result

Comment: Thanks . I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Some background:

- if you're running ASE 15.7 (or higher), you can declare a variable of type `(uni)text`
- the `textptr()` function returns a varbinary(16) value which is actually a pointer to where the text data resides in the database [in the manuals they typically show `@val = textptr(...)` which is a bit misleading because `textptr()` isn't returning the value of the text column but rather a pointer to the text column]
- an actual text column value can be accessed directly just like you would any other column
- the `writetext` command provides an alternative to the `update` command when it comes to writing a value into a text column; `update` is a logged operation while `writetext` is, by default, a non-logged operation

Some example SQL (using your table definition):

```
insert table_1 values ('1','original.old text value',getdate())
go

declare @ptr     varbinary(16),
        @unitext unitext,
        @varchar varchar(16384)

-- obtain text pointer and unitext value for a desired row

select  @ptr     = textptr(data_values),                  -- pointer to unitext column
        @unitext = data_values,                           -- actual unitext value
        @varchar = convert(varchar(16384),data_values)    -- unitext converted to character
from    table_1
where   id = '1'

select 'original' as 'when', @unitext as '@unitext', @varchar as '@varchar'

-- logged update of the data_values column

begin tran

update  table_1
set     data_values = 'update.new text value'
where   id = '1'

select  @unitext = data_values,
        @varchar = convert(varchar(16384),data_values)
from    table_1
where   id = '1'

select 'after update' as 'when', @unitext as '@unitext', @varchar as '@varchar'

-- non-logged update of the data_values column

writetext table_1.data_values @ptr 'writetext.new text value'

select  @unitext = data_values,
        @varchar = convert(varchar(16384),data_values)
from    table_1
where   id = '1'

select 'after writetext' as 'when', @unitext as '@unitext', @varchar as '@varchar'

-- rollback to original value

rollback tran

select  @unitext = data_values,
        @varchar = convert(varchar(16384),data_values)
from    table_1
where   id = '1'

select 'after rollback' as 'when', @unitext as '@unitext', @varchar as '@varchar'
go

 when             @unitext                      @varchar
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
 original         original.old text value       original.old text value

 when             @unitext                      @varchar
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
 after update     update.new text value         update.new text value

 when             @unitext                      @varchar
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
 after writetext  writetext.new text value      writetext.new text value

 when             @unitext                      @varchar
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
 after rollback   original.old text value       original.old text value
```

---

Edited:

- updated to pull the value into both a `unitext` variable and a `varchar` variable
- there are still some string-related functions that do not work with (uni)text so it may be necessary to work with the character version of the data
- also, if `varchar` happens to corrupt the data then it's possible to replace `varchar` with `univarchar` though the max length will need to be reduced from 16384 to 8192

Comment: Hi Mark! Thanks for the effort you put in. Only challenge I have is when we pass varchar(30) to convert function then we are limiting the size of text that can be converted from text field and whole text cannot be processed that is contained within text field.

Comment: `varchar(30)` was merely an example; I've updated my answer to show pulling the data into both `unitext` and `varchar(16384)` variables; see notes at the end of the post